# How can we determine the sample size sufficient for regression problems?

Tags: statistics, size, sample

I see some theoretical models for determining sample size for classification tasks based on desired sensitivity and/or specificity. However, it is difficult to find works on regression problem. I understand it is problem statement specific. But it would be nice to read upon similar problem for any regression task.

Comment: What means "required"? What is your criterion for sufficient sample size?

Comment: Yes, i meant sufficient. Also, i would like to know how to approach for a multivariate regression problem. For univariate, perhaps i can use this: https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Power/BS704_Power2.html#headingtaglink_1

Comment: My question is, what means "sufficient" to you? In your example with classification, you seem to have some threshold for sensitivity and specificity in mind. But what do you have in mind for regression? Do you maybe want the errors for the parameter estimations to be below a certain threshold?

Comment: Yes, i do have a criteria for errors. I want to regress to certain coordinates (provided in the ground truth). Let us assume i know how much am i allowed to deviate for each point in the 3d space. So for every point, i have the x,y, and z coordinates predicted. Further, i always estimate a set of 3 or 4 points which define a specific plane. So, i am not clear whether to go with point estimate for univariate case or  is there a multivariate approach.

Comment: any thoughts? please let me know.